# Need a good method to change (SQLite) column data type

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having a table with 'int' column. During software upgrade, I want to change it to 'long' data type. It seems SQLite does not provide an option (in alter statement) to change/modify column properties. Since I want to do an upgrade, the table might contain data which the user should not lose. So please suggest me a good method to change the column data type property without data loss.

One way suggested in the search links is to create a temporary table, copy the records from the existing table, delete the existing table, and rename the temporary table. I doubt that is efficient.

Your help appreciated!

Regards

Vivek Ragunathan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used the follow statements to change the type of the column.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS **TEMP_TABLE** (id integer primary key autoincrement, **col2change integer not null**, ...)

INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE SELECT * FROM EXISTING_TABLE

DROP TABLE EXISTING_TABLE

ALTER TABLE TEMP_TABLE RENAME TO EXISTING_TABLE
```

I changed the int type column in the existing table to integer type. For a few hundred rows, it was reasonably fast.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite3 columns do not have data types, only [affinities](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) -- there is no benefit in changing the column type from int to long.

If a wrapper program is truncating values before giving them to SQLite3, there is a way to fix this by editing the schema. It is a dangerous operation, so do it only after backing up your database. The schema is stored in the table `sqlite_master`; normally it is read-only, but you can modify it if you enable it with the [writable_schema](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_writable_schema) pragma. Be careful to only make changes that do not invalidate your data; you may change `int` to `long int` since they both have INTEGER affinity.

Comment: But the value held in the column is sensitive to int or long. If it is not long, data inserted in the column is truncated.

Comment: In that case it is not SQLite3 itself, but a wrapper API that is truncating values. See my answer addendum.

Comment: Are you using getLong?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getLong(int) ?

Comment: Actually I am inserting into a (system) table, which seems to have a long value. So you can say the scenario is equivalent to calling getLong?

Comment: Show us your code. You don't want to change the schema for the system table!

Comment: I am not changing the schema for the system table but my table which mimics a part of the schema of the system table. So when I insert the data from my table to the system table, the data is truncated because my table has int data type. And that's why I need to change the int data type of my table to long or something bigger so that it does cause any data loss.

Answer (score 1):

From SQLite documentation

> It is not possible to rename a column, remove a column, or add or
>   remove constraints from a table.

[Check this link](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Please do remember that column data types are not rigid in SQLite. [Check this link](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

**Edit:**
Following your comments on another answer, I guess the option you mentioned - working through the temp table - is the only one, which is not efficient off course.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a new colum, copy the values form the old to the new column, delete the old column and then rename the new column to the old name

Comment: Seems to be a good idea but see one of the comments above which refers to the SQLite documentation. It says that a column cannot be renamed or removed!

Comment: is it possble to rename a table? then you could create a complete new table and trasfer the data

Comment: Yeah it is. And that's what my question is. Is that efficient? Is there an alternative method to achieve the column data type change?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is **no** way in Android to change column data types once a table is created and used. The practiced way is to make a new table and copy the data which you read about

Comment: I guess that is true, and I am trying it!